# Output selected text with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have added an event listener to the entire document. However, something strange is happening. Only text in the input field is being displayed when selected. Nothing happens when I select text in the `<p>` tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a "select" event to an element.</p>

  <input style="width:100%" type="text" value="Only text in the input field is being displayed when selected!" id="myText">

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("select", myFunction);

    function myFunction() {
      let selection = window.getSelection().toString();
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = selection;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Per MDN: "The event [select] is not available for all elements in all languages. For example, in HTML, select events can be dispatched only on form <input type="text"> and <textarea> elements." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/select_event

Comment: @ Luca Kiebel I think you misunderstand what i'm trying to do. I'm not trying to set the value on the input field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The select event is only available for *input* elements:

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/select_event):

> The event is not available for all elements in all languages. For
>   example, in HTML, select events can be dispatched only on form  and  elements.

So alternatively we can use a `mouseup` event to check the text selection.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p id="test">This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a "select" event to an element.</p>

  <input style="width:100%" type="text" value="Only text in the input field is being displayed when selected!" id="myText">
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
    if(document.getSelection()){
      document.querySelector("#demo").textContent = document.getSelection();
    }else if(window.getSelection()){
      document.querySelector("#demo").textContent = document.getSelection();
    }else if(document.selection){
      document.querySelector("#demo").textContent = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

No select event for p elements. Alternative could be to use a mouse up event.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a "select" event to an element.</p>

  <input style="width:100%" type="text" value="Only text in the input field is being displayed when selected!" id="myText">

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
  
  function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
   }

    document.addEventListener("select", myFunction);

    function myFunction() {
      let selection = window.getSelection().toString();
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = selection;
    }
    
    document.onmouseup = function() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getSelectionText();
    };
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a "mouseup" listener on the DOM.  You can then use the "getSelection" method on the Window object to get a [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object.  From there, a simple call to the "toString" method will give you the text selected.

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseup", checkForSelection);
function checkForSelection(evt){
  var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
  if ( selectedText ){
    console.log("Selected Text: " + selectedText);
  } else {
    console.log("No Text Selected");
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Text in paragraph 1</p>
<p>More Text in another paragraph</p>
</div>
```